# Android WebView Transient Audio Focus

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a WebView within my app and it plays a short sound via an html audio tag.  The problem is it steals audio focus from the rest of the app or external audio player and does not return it.

Is there a way have the webview request the audio focus as transient and return audio focus to the app/external player when done playing the audio tag?

Added a webview to an app that has an audio tag that streams a short audio stream on load.  Added a media player to the App that plays background noise.  Added an AudioFocus listener to the app.  App gains focus, plays audio.  When the webview is loaded, app loses audio focus and webview plays short audio.  WebView does not request audio as transient.  Audio Focus is not returned to app when done playback.